# VK API Не могу получить полный список всех участников группы ВКонтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем привет. Написал код который по идеи должен получить всех участников группы а он получает только часть, почему не понимаю.

Есть группа - https://vk.com/stiforp_1 я знаю что в ней 9680 участников, но скрипт выдает мне только 3749 . Не могу понять, почему?

Вот что сочинил на данный момент.

```
$page = 0;
$limit = 1000;
$users = array();
do {

    $offset = $page * $limit;

    //Получаем список пользователей
    $request_params = [
        'group_id'     => "stiforp_1",
        "offset"       => $offset,
        "count"        => $limit,
        "fields"       => "bdate,online",
        'access_token' => $vk_info["token"]
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($request_params).'&v=6.76');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $members = curl_exec($ch);
    $members = json_decode($members,true);
    curl_close($ch);
    //Спим
    usleep(333333);

    foreach($members['response']['items'] as $user ) {
        $users[]= $user; // добавляем юзера к юзерам
    }

    //Увеличиваем страницу
    $page++;

} while( $members['response']['count'] > $offset + $limit );


echo '<pre>';
print_r($users);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Это вполне возможно из-за настроек приватности у части пользователей либо удаленных пользователей, как тебе уже ответили. Протестируй на какой-нибудь своей группе или задай вопрос поддержке ВКонтакте, так как проблема не в коде 99%.